# Sonata admin, override select in template?

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

I'm using sonata admin and i am overriding a template.

I created a select in this template, and when I display  the page, I can't see my select, but a html code with UL and LI.

It seems Sonata override select in his template by his code.

How can i remove that ? I want MY select and not the select overrided by sonata.

Answer (score 3):

Sonata uses [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), a javascript library to customize the render of select elements.

To disable select2 on your select you need to add the attribute data-sonata-select2="false" :

`<select data-sonata-select2="false"></select>`

Related code in sonata:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/public/Admin.js#L76

Comment: Shortcut in your formMapper on the field: ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model',
    array(
        'attr'=>array('data-sonata-select2'=>'false')
    )
) Source: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/select2.html#disable-select2-on-some-form-elements/select2.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn of select2 for the whole sonata:

```
sonata_admin:
    options:
        use_select2:    false # disable select2
```

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/select2.html